# remove article name from SP slider

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a joomla 3.6 with a Helix 3 template and i downloaded a SP smart slider, I have inserted 4 images. My problem are that the "slider" shows the article name on all images.

How can I remove this "caption"?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can try to change 'Title Type' to 'Custom Title' and left it empty
2. you can hide it by adding css display:none; for this element
3. Create overwrite sp smart slide module view 
   https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides
   then you need to edit file template file in (for example)
   /templates/your_active_template/html/mod_sp_smart_slider/nivo_slider/view.php

if you use nivo_slider theme you can remove only image title attribute:

```
title="#sp-smart-caption-<?php echo $index ?>"
```